# How to define the site to be used in BrowserTestBase on a multisite?

Tags: testing

I am working on a multi site where there is no database defined in the default directory, so whenever I run a Functional test extending BrowserTestBase I get the following error:

```
copy(/var/www/drupal-int/docroot/sites/default/default.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I'm not really sure why the files were removed in the first place and I don't want to add them back in there in case there was a good reason for removing them. Is there a way to define the site to use for the test?

My simple test:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\my_module\Functional;

use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;

/**
 * Simple test to ensure that main page loads with module enabled.
 *
 * @group dnsw_scheduler_workbench_integration
 */
class LoadTest extends BrowserTestBase {

  /**
   * Modules to enable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = ['my_module'];

  /**
   * A user with permission to administer site configuration.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\user\UserInterface
   */
  protected $user;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->user = $this->drupalCreateUser(['administer site configuration']);
    $this->drupalLogin($this->user);
  }

  /**
   * Tests that the home page loads with a 200 response.
   */
  public function testLoad() {
    $this->drupalGet(Url::fromRoute('<front>'));
    $this->assertResponse(200);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your existing sites are used during a fonctionnal test, drupal creates a fresh install defined by your static attribute `$modules` and the `setUp()` method.

So, you should get the `default.settings.php` file back (and create a `/sites/simpletest` folder)